# Make Chrome media controls larger?

Tags: google-chrome

I happen to browse some audio files from within the browser, connecting directly to the audio files themselves in the URL, and some of them are relatively long. The media control, so the horizontal scrolling bar, is way too small to be able to browse the audio file with any amount of precision.
How do I make that bar bigger?

Comment: This is not a permanent solution, because it goes away if you navigate away or refresh the page, but what I do in a pinch is the following. Right click on the bar, select "Inspect", and in the CSS styles under `element.style {` type in `width:90%` or `width:1500px` or similar. This forces Chrome to render the bar that way.